# JQuery ajax post problem with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a list of records which loop from mysql table, for each record i had assigned an onclick function in order to pass the data for mysql query use to avoid page refresh whenever it was call,

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='PlayMV(\"".$rows["v_type"]."\",\"".$rows["v_id"]."\");'>Play</a>
```

below is passing values to jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PlayMV(data1, data2){
$.post("mtv.php", { var1: "data1", var2: "data2" },
    function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
});
}
</script>
```

here comes the problem, the "$('#result').html(data);" was always returned me a whole page in source code instead of held only the values, what I want is only able to post 'data1' and 'data2' and assigned into a php variable and mysql query like below:

```
$var1 = data1;
$var2 = data2;
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE mvtype='".$var1."' AND mvid='".$var2."'");
```

how to use JSON to pass those data into mysql query to retrieve the final result, can anyone help?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

your script mtv.php will recieve them in the $_POST global.

you should be able to get the params with $_POST['var1'], $_POST['var2']

Script should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PlayMV(data1, data2){
        $.post("mtv.php", { var1: data1, var2: data2 },
            function(data){
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

You had quotes round the values.

**EDIT**

Oh, if you want some data BACK from php, you can return XML or JSON, simply alert(data) to see what IS being returned just now.

In mtv.php, use json_encode() and echo it, this will get returned as 'data' which you can then do something liek this:

Example return JSON: {'thing': 1234}

```
var myObject = $.parseJSON(data);    

alert(myObject.thing);
```

The alert would display 1234.

Comment: I think he actually just set the variables to those strings for the sake of the example/test.

Comment: Nope... they are parameters of the function, check his Q you will see they are quoted... while his call is passing in alternative data $rows["v_type"] and $rows["v_id"].

Answer (score 1):

How do you retrieve the data in php? You should be able to fetch it like so:

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
$var2 = $_POST['var2'];
```

Comment: Hi, i can retrieve the data properly assigned in php variable,

this is the hardest part for me to parse into mysql query,
    function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    }

please advise me for more json sample on how to use it.

Comment: Ah, your question did not exactly state that this was the issue :) Just put your results into a php array, then do a json_encode on that array and echo out the result. You can then use that result from javascript.